# Android fragment backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have shopping basket fragment in my app. I want to show only one instance of that fragment. For example:

```
[1] [2] [my basket fragment] [3] [4]
```

Then I need to display busket fragment again and replace it onto the top of the `BackStack`. The BackStack must become like this:

```
[1] [2] [3] [4] [my basket fragment]
```

How is it possible? Because remove fragment by tag leaves empty view without content.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you are not wanting to have the basket fragment in your backstack. That way, if the user presses back it wont show. To do that, don't add it to the backstack.

```
BasketFragment yourInstanceOfTheBasketFragment = new BasketFragment();

// to show the fragment
getFragmentManager()
          .beginTransaction()
          .replace(R.id.container, yourInstanceOfTheBasketFragment)
          .commit();

// to remove the current fragment, and show next in backstack.
getFragmentManager()
          .popBackStack();
```

Also, note that `removeFragment` will only do that. It wont add anything. So if you are wanting to remove a fragment and show what is below it in the stack, call `getFragmentManager.popBackStack();`